# How to handle 'drawend' event in a non blocking way in OpenLayers?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, openlayers

### Here is the situation :

- I have got a map, based on OpenLayers 4.6.5, with two layers : one
  raster background and a vector layer upon which I allow drawing
  polygons
- I would like to launch some lengthy calculations upon
  termination of the draw of a polygon

### I manage to do something with

`drawingObj.on('drawend', e => do_some_lengthy_calc(e.feature));`
`drawingObj` being a `ol.interaction.Draw`

but this call is blocking the flow: the map interaction is frozen (no ability to draw another polygon) and the completion of the drawing only intervenes at the end of my calculations.

What should I do then ?
Thanks for your help

Comment: I don't understand what is actually a problem. why can't you draw another polygon?

Comment: I don't really know why but I can't draw any new polygon until my calculation (triggered by event 'drawend') finishes:  
[here is a gif showing situation](https://i.imgur.com/lCDqWPn.gif)   
(the calculation duration depends of polygon size and I also set a clearing of source when 'drawstart' but it's not part of the problem)

Comment: it's weired. calculation of 4-edge polygon should be finished in a very short time. how could this make a delay so long like that?

Comment: the thing is I am launching some lengthy calculations after draw object triggers 'drawend' event and apparently it waits for the calculation to finish before closing the polygon and allowing to draw another one. I would like my calculation to be really in background (non blocking)

Comment: the code you added on the question seems no problem. could you share working fildde something that reproduces it?